# How do I rotate an environment texture?

Tags: texturing, world

I've loaded an HDR image into my scene as an environment texture. However, I need to rotate the image, and so far, haven't found a way. I assume this is possible, but I need to know HOW.

Comment: A case of [Rotating blender texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/167610/15265)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In the World section of the Material nodes add a Texture Coordinate node and a mapping node to control the placement of the Environment texture. By changing the rotation on the mapping node you can place the HDR where you need it.

[image]

As of Blender 2.8x, the World section is part of the new [Shader Editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/shader_editor/index.html):

[image]

[image]

Comment: The environment texture stops working as soon as I add the Mapping Node.

Comment: @Black for new questions use the blue [**Ask Question**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) box at the top right of the page, not the comments section.

Comment: How is it a new question, it is a comment saying that your solution does not work. I just get a solid color view.

Comment: @Black It is a new question. The title: "environment texture stops working as soon as I add the Mapping Node", then it should be followed by a link to this question, an explanation of what you did, an image illustrating  what happened when you added the node and any other information you want to add.

Comment: I followed your instructions 1:1

Answer (score -5):

You need to load the HDR image from the "environment texture node".
The environment picture in your scene will not work alone.