# Rotating blender texture

Tags: node-editor

So I wanted to make a circle with lines on it like this, going this way.
[image: How I want the lines]

But when I set up my nodes (like this),
[image: my node setup]
the lines looked like this

[image: How it turned out]
I want to find out how to rotate the image but it is using blender's "wave texture node" And I can't seem to find out how to do that.

How do I rotate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before your Wave node, put in a Texture Coordinate node (using generate) and this goes into a Mapping node. You can then modify the rotation (depends on your orientation) but here is my setup with a before shot and after shot

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Comment: Oh duh. I tried all that but I did it AFTER the wave texture. Thanks a tone.

Comment: Note that you have to apply the object's rotation if you modified it in object mode with CTRL + A or else the mapping node rotations may be inverted