# How do I save a rotated HDRI from Blender?

Tags: texturing, export

I just need to export a rotated HDRI background image. I rotated the image:
[How do I rotate an environment texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47833/how-do-i-rotate-an-environment-texture) 
How do I save it?

Also, if I could choose between HDRI or 6 cube images that would be great.

Answer (score 5):

1. add camera, rotate it on 90deg. by 'X' axis., and select Panoramic Type with Equirectangular Panorama type.
2. use Cycles render engine with just 1 sample.
3. don't use Filmic View transform.
4. set Output dimensions as environment map.
5. render an image and save it in EXR or HDR format!

[image: panoramic camera environment]

Comment: Would be good to mention an output file format as well ...