# How are HDRIs used for the foreground?

Tags: rendering, hdri

I was looking at HDRI Haven and some of the example renders appear to use the HDRI as part of the foreground.

For example this hdri:
https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?h=old_bus_depot

In the example render below they used the part of the hdri in the blue square.  How is this achieved?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the HDR as environment texture.

Just line up the camera so that it sees that part of the environment.

[image]

Or rotate the environment image until you see the section you are looking for.

[How do I rotate an environment texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47833/how-do-i-rotate-an-environment-texture)

To have shadows of the object create a plane and use it as shadow catcher.

Comment: Thanks!  If I want it to be as hi-res as in the example render, do I need to download the 16k version?

Comment: 3D os all about optimization. Download the one that works for your needs, and that doesn't exceed the capabilities of your computer.